# Filtering and subsetting R dataframe based on selected variable/column names

Tags: r, filtering, subset

I am trying to subset a large data set with many variables/columns names, say ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ...,ax20, bx1...bx20...zx1...zx20. For example, suppose the subset data I want to obtain are on variables ax3, ax5, ax11, ax19,..., bx3, bx5, cx11, cx19,...,zx3, zx5, zx11, zx19.

I have tried the following code in R but it is becoming very lengthy and cumbersome.

```
setwd("")
abc<- read.table("abc.txt", header=TRUE)
new.abc<-data.frame(abc$ax3,abc$ax5,abc$ax5,abc$ax11,abc$ax19,  
abc$bx3,abc$bx5,abc$bx5,abc$bx11,abc$bx19)
```

The code is becoming longer as I need to continue with cx3, cx5, cx11, cx19,...,zx3, xz5, zx11, zx19. I am looking for an alternative approach that can avoid this lengthy coding. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about you subset like a matrix something like `new.abc =[,''names"]` and the variable names could be a vector with the names of the columns you want to extract

Answer (score 3):

You could create columns programmatically. If they follow the same structure as mentioned in the question, we can do

```
cols <- c(outer(paste0(letters, "x"), c(3, 5, 11, 19), paste0))
cols
#[1] "ax3"  "bx3"  "cx3"  "dx3"  "ex3"  "fx3"  "gx3"  "hx3"  "ix3"  "jx3"  "kx3"...
```

and then use it to subset the dataframe

```
new.abc[, cols]
```

If we also want to preserve column order, we can use `gtools::mixedsort`

```
new.abc[, gtools::mixedsort(cols)]
```

Comment: thanks it's very helpful. What about when you want to restrict the letters to "a" and "p" inclusively.

Comment: @TRichard use `letters[1:16]` i.e `c(outer(paste0(letters[1:16], "x"), c(3, 5, 11, 19), paste0))`